# Avoid duplicates in SELECT

Tags: sql

possible a super simple question, but I just don't get it now. Here we go:
I have a table

```
id | lang1  | sth | sth2
1  | "one"  | "x" | "y"
1  | "one"  | "x" | "y"
2  | "two"  | "y" | "z"
1  | "one"  | "x" | "y"
3  | "three"| "z" | "a"
```

And I need a SELECT, that gives me everything without duplicates.

```
1  | "one"  | "x" | "y"
2  | "two"  | "y" | "z"
3  | "three"| "z" | "a"
```

So possibly something like (Pseudo code, doesn't work, just for the idea)

`SELECT id, lang1, sth, sth2 FROM tbl GROUP BY id, lang1`

OR

`SELECT DISTINCT(id, lang1), sth, sth2 FROM tbl`

Thanks,
Bernd

Comment: It looks like you're aware of both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` - is there a reason that those will not work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just plain simple `DISTINCT` will do

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, lang1, sth, sth2
FROM tbl
```

`DISTINCT(id, lang1)` won't work because `DISTINCT` is a keyword, not a function. Function calls in SQL have parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

`DISTINCT` applies to all `expression/column` so use it

```
select distinct id, lang1, sth, sth2
from table t;
```

However, `GROUP BY` clause applies whenever you have to find *identical* values

So, you can express

```
select id, lang1, sth, sth2
from table t
group by id, lang1, sth, sth2;
```